Cannot get datepicker field to display August as the the first month available
Currently the first month that displays is September. I want it to be August so that the customer has to move the calender forward to September in order for the field to block off the dates I listed. Any help would be appreciated.
function(field,form){
  var datepicker = form.getFieldByName('RICHBOROopeningdate1').getDatePicker();
  datepicker.settings.beforeShowDay = function(date) {
    var day = date.getDay(); 
    var disabledDates = ["2024-09-01","2024-09-07","2024-09-08","2024-09-14",
                         "2024-09-15","2024-09-21","2024-09-22","2024-09-28",
                         "2024-09-29","2024-10-05","2024-10-06","2024-10-12",
                         "2024-10-13","2024-10-19","2024-10-20","2024-10-19",
                         "2024-10-26","2024-10-27","2024-11-02","2024-11-03",
                         "2024-11-09","2024-11-10","2024-11-16","2024-11-17",
                         "2024-11-23","2024-11-24","2024-11-30","2024-09-02",
                         "2024-09-03","2024-09-04","2024-09-09","2024-09-10",
                         "2024-09-12","2024-09-13","2024-09-16","2024-09-17",
                         "2024-09-18","2024-09-20","2024-09-23","2024-09-24",
                         "2024-09-25","2024-09-26","2024-09-27","2024-09-30",
                         "2024-10-01","2024-10-02","2024-10-03","2024-09-10",
                         "2024-09-05","2024-10-04","2024-09-19","2024-09-11"]
    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
    return [ disabledDates.indexOf(string) == -1 ]    
  }
}

I've searched all over and can not seem to find something that will work. I'm new to working with JavaScript.

Are you using the jQuery UI datepicker? I cannot find any datepicker library for jQuery that uses getDatePicker() - perhaps it is a custom function you made? Same goes for getFieldByName.You should include the necessary libraries and put all your code together in a snippet, I was going to do it for you, but I was unsure of which library/libraries you are using.
